# How to restart a docker container based on a port service failure

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I have a couple of services running on a single container. Here are some details:

root@f5612e928609:/srv# netstat -ano -p tcp

Active Internet connections (servers and established)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name     Timer

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/python             off (0.00/0/0)

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45800           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7/python             off (0.00/0/0)

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:57864        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)

tcp        0      0 172.18.0.5:58942        172.18.0.3:6379         ESTABLISHED 9/python             off (0.00/0/0)

udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:34701        0.0.0.0:*                           -                    off (0.00/0/0)

Sometimes a service running on port 45800 silently fails and we need to restart the docker container manually. Is there a way to monitor this specific port inside this running container for alerts or auto-restart policy?

Comment: A better practice would be to run only one service in a container.  If you're using this in a clustered environment like Kubernetes, its health-check system can observe that the single service in a container has failed and restart the whole container; if there are multiple things in a container, though, this sort of restart policy will restart all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but you are doing it wrong. A better approach would be running each service in isolated container, and use some tool to manage containers lifecycles. If you don't currently such tool, I recommend to start with docker-compose.